# How to properly extend Django user?

Tags: django, model, customization

I want to extend the Django user class in Django 1.7.1 to drop the first name and last name and to put a unique constraint on the e-mail address. So far I have this custom model to change the constraints/fields:

```
class ExtUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    class Meta:
        # Django 1.7.2?
        #default_related_name = 'user'
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
        abstract = False

    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and '
                    '@/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@+-]+$', _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ])
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=75, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

And I modified the settings file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'ext.ExtUser'
```

I can login to the Django admin, but when I try to edit a user, I get the following exception:

```
ProgrammingError at /api/extuser/1/
column auth_user_groups.extuser_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...oup"."id" = "auth_user_groups"."group_id" ) WHERE "auth_user...
```

I guess the user foreign key in other tables is formed based upon the class name... How do I fix this? I tried using the default_related_name field in the model meta class, but that had no positive effect.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Kind regards,
K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found a solution for my problem: make sure that the custom user model class is named "User" instead of "ExtUser" and everything will keep on working.

Easy! :-)

Comment: It doesn't need to be named "User." It can still be "ExtUser" as long as you specify that inside of the settings. Set AUTH_USER_MODEL to your_app.ExtUser in your settings. Ex: AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.ExtUser'